# Representation of a unitary in terms of a self-adjoint operator

Tags: complex-analysis, functional-analysis, c-star-algebras

If $A$ is a $C^\ast$-algebra and $u\in A$ is unitary and $\tau_u : A \to \mathbb C$ is the evaluation map why can $\tau_u$ no map to any number in  $(-\infty, 0]$?

This is used in the proof here:

Claim: Let $A$ be a $C^\ast$-algebra and $u$ be unitary. If $\sigma (u) \neq \mathbf T$ then there exists $a \in A$ self-adjoint s.t. $u=e^{ia}$.

Proof: We may assume that $-1 \notin \sigma (u)$ and that $A$ is commutative. Let $\varphi : A \to C_0 (\Omega (A))$ be the Gelfand representation and let $f = \varphi (u)$ and $\ln : \mathbb C \setminus (-\infty , 0]\to \mathbb C$ the principal branch of the logarithm. Then $g = \ln \circ f$ is a well-defined element of $C_0 (\Omega)$....

Why is $g$ well-defined?

Comment: What is the image of $\varphi(u)$? $\varphi(u)(\Omega(A)) =\,?$

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your comment. In this case $\varphi$ is an isometric isomorphism so $\varphi (A) = A = C_0 (\Omega (A))$. But $f \in C_0$ can be negative?

Comment: @DanielFischer Ah sorry ignore my previous comment. I remember that $\sigma(u) = \{\tau (u) \mid \tau \in \Omega (A)\}\cup \{0\}$ (if $A$ is not unital). But why is $\sigma (u) \cap (-\infty , 0]=\varnothing$?

Comment: @DanielFischer Thank you for your help!! So much! I get it: $\sigma (u) \subset \mathbf T$ so the only value that can cause complications is $-1$ -- which is not in the spectrum by assumption!

Comment: You can say more: if $u$ is unitary and if there is some point in the spectrum $\lambda \in\sigma(u)$ that is not an eigenvalue, then $u=e^{ia}$ for a selfadjoint $a$. This can't be easily stated in a $C^{\star}$ setting, though.